# A bit complicated eval in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, eval

I need a special behavior from eval, to evaluate strings like:

```
'5a + 6b + 3a + 11b'
```

into

```
'8a + 17b'
```

Is it possible? If it is, can you give a proper example? I found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/sketchupruby/browse_thread/thread/6c9bb7cfc76a5cda) example recently, where the talk was about evaluating strings with meters and inches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way it is written, that's not valid ruby syntax, so it can't be `eval`ed.

You have two options:

a) Don't use eval. I would think that this is the best option, but I supposed that depends on the context.

b) Change the syntax to `5.a + 6.b + 3.a + 11.b` and define appropriate a and b methods, like so:

```
class Expr
  attr_accessor :a,:b
  def initialize(a,b)
    @a, @b = a,b
  end

  def +(other)
    Expr.new(a + other.a, b + other.b)
  end

  def inspect
    "<expr: #{a}a + #{b}b>"
  end
end

class Numeric
  def a
    Expr.new(self, 0)
  end

  def b
    Expr.new(0, self)
  end
end

5.a + 6.b + 3.a + 11.b #=> <expr: 8a + 17b>
```

Comment: In general, I'm trying to find a way of oversimplifying mathematical algebraic linear equations. So basically there will be N of unknown variables. I've already found a solution to avoid this unnecessary and complicated evaluation. Still thanx for your answer! Will try to generalize it in my leisure time.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem here is not related to Ruby's eval. You need a simple interpreter (parser+evaluator) to interpret the above mentioned expressions. There are some solutions for your problem but you need to give a proper explanation for the syntax you are trying to parse.

For example in your case I would do something like this:

```
res = ['a','b'].map do |sym| 
  '5a + 6b + 3a + 11b'.scan(/(\d+)#{sym}/).flatten.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x.to_i}.to_s + sym
end.join(" + ")
puts res #=> 8a + 17b
```

Comment: Regexps are still a kind of 'dark forest' for me. Still, will try to look deeper into your example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess depending on your problem this might be very complex. I do not know a library for mathematical optimization in ruby. I fear it is not possible with ruby eval. But you probably could write your own optimizer. If you think of the expression that way:

- +

  - *

    - 5
    - a
  - *

    - 6
    - b
  - *

    - 3
    - a
  - *

    - 11
    - b

You can group summands with equal variable, summarize the numbers and create a new expression string. For the parsing [Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/) could be worth a look.

Comment: Parsing an arithmetic expression is the introductory example in the Treetop docu, if I remember correctly. Good luck with your computer algebra system, though!